# Tableau : Offset stacked bar chart by a negative number

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

We have a specific business requirement for visualizing data in a certain way.

[image: Current Data]

The above graph needs to be offset by the "negative yellow bar" as below.

[image: Expected Result]

I have tried the Gantt chart method but it only works for a single bar chart.

I couldn't visualize multiple stacked bar charts.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the Gantt mark type for this if you write a calculated field to compute the offset of each bar. You probably would do that using a table calculation, so you'll have to learn about partitioning and addressing of table calcs. Look for examples of divergent stacked bar charts, such as http://www.datarevelations.com/all-politicians-lie-some-more-than-others

Comment: @AlexBlakemore : Thanks, will have a look at the divergent charts.